# Búsquedas con Python de texto en diferentes líneas de fichero de texto

Tags: python, bucles, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo una duda sobre cómo poder leer un archivo de texto en Python por partes. Me explico, el fichero a leer tiene 33.000 líneas, quiero extraer una información de las 31000 primeras y otra desde la 31000 hasta el final. Mi código extrae de todo el fichero pero no sé seccionar. Del fichero de texto "Libro" quiero guardar unas líneas determinadas en un fichero de texto "Texto1" y otras en otro fichero "Texto2" pero no doy con el bucle que tengo que implementar para decirle que busque desde la 0 a la 31000 para texto1 y de la 31000 hasta el final para texto2:

```
fw = open('Texto1')
fw2 = open ('Texto2')

with open("Libro", "r") as f:
    archivo_por_lineas = f.readlines()
    for numlinea, linea in enumerate(archivo_por_lineas):
        if not ('.') in linea:
            if (' ') in linea:
                linea=linea.replace(' ','')
                linea=linea.replace('   ','')
                if ('palabra1') in linea:
                    fw.write (linea)
        if ('Segunda parte') in linea:
            fw.closed
            print (numlinea) -> A partir de esta línea quiero buscar otros campos como 'palabra2'
fw2.close()
```

Comment: Agrega un contador de lineas grabadas `cont`. Luego, antes de grabar, pregunta `if cont > 30000: fw2.write() else fw.write()` .

Comment: El ejemplo que estás dando es muy especifico. Que pasa si el archivo tiene 100.000 lineas? debe seccionarse en partes de 30000 lineas y cada sección tendrá un trato distinto? O separás el texto en dos en la linea 31000, quedandote pedazos de 31000 y 61000? En resumen, podrías decirnos el comportamiento esperado en un escenario más general?

Comment: ¿Que tienen que ver los reemplazos con la pregunta? Además el código no compila (`fw.closed`)? Edita tu pregunta, corrige los problemas y completa el código.